# Determining point of intersection in a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide, intersections

I'm finding it difficult to draw the triangle as in the figure below:

[image]

I am not being able to determine the "E point".

Consequently, "A point".

The lengths do not matter, but the angles.

The `DB` segments have the same length as `DE`.

The `AD` segments have the same length as `DC`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){D}
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){B}

\tkzLabelPoint[left](D){$D$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}

\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](D,B)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is possible, but the E point is complicated to determine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`E` is the easiest point to find, that's just a matter of using polar coordinates. If `D` is at `(0,0)`, and `B` is at `(90:1)` (polar coordinate, angle 90 radius 1), then `E` is at `(140:1)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\coordinate [label=below:$D$] (D) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (90:1);
\coordinate [label=above left:$E$] (E) at (140:1);

% draw invisible, horizontal path from D
\path [overlay,name path=A] (D) -- ++(-20,0);
% draw invisible path through B and E
\path [overlay,name path=B] (B) -- ($(E)!-20cm!(B)$);
% find intersection of above paths, name it A
\path [name intersections={of=A and B, by={A}}] node[left] at (A) {$A$};

% reflect A around D to get C
\coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at ($(D)!-1!(A)$);

\draw (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;
\draw [dashed] (E) -- (D) -- (B);

% draw angles
\pic [draw,angle radius=1cm,angle eccentricity=1.3, "$40^\circ$"] {angle=E--D--A};
\pic [draw,angle radius=1cm,angle eccentricity=1.3, "$x$"] {angle=B--C--D};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used TikZ because I don't remember the `tkz-euclide` syntax, and couldn't be bothered at the moment to look in the manual.

Comment: There is no need `tkz-euclide`. That's great.

Comment: @LCarvalho You didn't delete `\end{tikzpicture}`, you added the new `\draw` command *after* it. I'll fix.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a TikZ solution without `intersections` library that use that AD = tan(65°)BD.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \path
      (0,0) coordinate[label=below:$D$] (D)
      (90:1) coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B)
      (140:1) coordinate [label=above left:$E$] (E)
      (180:{tan(65)}) coordinate [label=below:$A$] (A)
      (0:{tan(65)}) coordinate [label=below:$C$] (C);

    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \draw[dashed] (E) -- (D) -- (B);
    \path
      (D) pic[draw, angle eccentricity=1.5,"$40^{\circ}$"]{angle=E--D--A}
      (A) pic[draw, angle eccentricity=1.5,"$x$"]{angle=B--C--A};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A way to do this with MetaPost, for whom it may interest, with the help of the Metafun format for drawing the angles and for labels.

I've tried to parameterize the problem. The coordinates of points B and D, and the value of the desired angle, can be changed at will. Point E is simply built by rotating the point B around point D. The location of point A is found by MetaPost itself by computing the intersection between the straight line (DB) rotated by an angle 90°, and the straight line (BE), through the following instruction:

```
A = whatever[D, D + (B-D) rotated 90] = whatever[B, E];
```

I've included the code in a LuaLaTeX program, so that it can be typesetted more easily.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
u := 3cm;
alpha := 40;
pair A, B, C, D, E;
D = origin;
B = u*(0, 1);
E = B rotatedaround (D, 90-alpha);
A = whatever[D, D + (B-D) rotated 90] = whatever[B, E];
C = A rotatedaround (D, 180);
beginfig(1);
    draw A -- B -- C -- cycle;
    draw B -- D -- E dashed evenly;
    anglelength := cm;
    drawdblarrow anglebetween (D--A, D--E, "\SI{" & decimal alpha & "}{\degree}");
    anglelength := 1.25cm;
    drawdblarrow anglebetween (C--A, C--B, "$x$");
    anglemethod := 2; anglelength := .2cm;
    draw anglebetween (D--C, D--B, "");
    freelabel("$A$", A, D); freelabel("$B$", B, D); freelabel("$C$", C, D);
    freelabel("$D$", D, B); freelabel("$E$", E, D);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution with `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
% definition
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(90:2){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(140:2){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,0){I}
% calculation
    \tkzInterLL(B,E)(I,D) \tkzGetPoint{A}
    \tkzDefPointBy[symmetry=center D](A) \tkzGetPoint{C}
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments[dashed](D,E D,B)
% labels and marks
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](D){$D$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above left](E){$E$}  
    \tkzMarkAngles[size=1](E,D,A B,C,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.75](A,D,E){$40^{\circ}$} 
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.75](B,C,A){$x$}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]